# URL from PushNotificationChannelManager cannot be found

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I'm building a Windows Phone 8.1 app that communicates with a Windows Service with SignalR.
The URL I recieve from:

```
PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync()
```

Looks like: "http://notificationserver.microsoft.com/XXXXXXXXXX...

Here is my first problem. When I read about this on several webpages, it states that the URL-domain should contain with "notify.windows.com" or am I wrong?

When I try to post a push-notification to WNS with the URL I receive:

```
The remote name could not be resolved: 'notificationserver.microsoft.com'
```

Could the problem be something with my authentication when trying to send the notification or do I receive the wrong URL in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rebooting the computer I got the correct URL and it seems to work...
The one thing I can think about is that during that the emulator was running I noticed that the "Notificatiojn Service" in WMAppManifest.xml was set to "MPN" and I changed that to "WNS" without restarting the emulator (but I did uninstall the app and re-run it)...

Hopefully this will help someone... =)

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem by disabling notifications simulation and restarting the emulator.

(In universal apps I couldn't find any MPN refference in the manifest)